# c# Stream.ReadAsync reads zero bytes, although the end of the stream was not reached

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-8.1, streaming, mp4

I am trying to send an mp4 Stream using http, but everytime my loop breaks during the first iteration, because ReadAsync returns 0. I don't get why, because I check whether the stream is empty and of course it is not.

This is what I got so far:

```
while (camera.VideoStream.AsStream().Length == 0);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (true)
{
    int bytesRead = await camera.VideoStream.AsStream().ReadAsync(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("End of Stream");
        break;
    }
    await output.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    await output.FlushAsync();
}
```

camera.VideoStream is an IRandomAccessStream.

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the position of the stream when you're trying to read it?

You may need to .Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin).